# CSV to mongoDB or JSON to MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, csv

Which one is the fastest menthod to import 5MB size raw data

Processing into CSV and then import to MongoDB? or JSON to MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest is BSON.  You can load it directly into MongoDB using `mongoimport`.  This should be significantly faster than either CSV or JSON.  Between CSV and JSON I doubt it matters much, you should choose whatever makes more sense for your application (e.g. CSV is not as flexible as JSON).